# Try to solve solid transportation as linear programming in python but getting key error 1

Tags: python

This code produces key error 1

```
from pulp import*
import numpy as np

Supply = {1: 10, 2:30, 3:50, 4:60}

Source = range(1,5) #{1,2,3,4}

Demand = {5: 40, 6:30, 7:80}

Destination = range(5,8)  

capacity = {8:60, 9:50, 10:40}

Conveyance = range(8,11) #{8,9,10}

Cost = {(1,5,8):6.099180273,(1,5,9):6.107372594, (1,5,10):6.123724357, (2,5,8):4.494441011, (2,5,9):4.50555213, (2,5,10):4.527692569, (3,5,8):17.69745744,(3,5,9):17.70028248, (3,5,10):17.70593121, (4,5,8):20.10472581, (4,5,9):20.10721264, (4,5,10):20.11218536, (1,6,8):9.859006035, (1,6,9):9.864076237, (1,6,10):39.874208829, (2,6,8):11.05441088,(2,6,9):11.05893304, (2,6,10):11.06797181,(3,6,8):15.13935269, (3,6,9):15.14265499,
(3,6,10):15.14925741, (4,6,8):28.6041955, (4,6,9):28.60594344, (4,6,10):28.609439, (1,7,8):14.21970464, (1,7,9): 14.22322045,(1,7,10):14.23024947, (2,7,8):17.81010949, (2,7,9):17.81291666, (2,7,10):17.81852968, (3,7,8):2.049390153,(3,7,8):2.073644135, (3,7,10):2.121320344, (4,7,8):18.79361594, (4,7,9):18.79627623, (4,7,10):18.80159568}

prob = LpProblem("Material Supply Problem", LpMinimize)

routes = [(i,j,k) for i in Source for j in Destination for k in Conveyance]

Amount_vars = LpVariable.dicts("amountship", (Source, Destination, Conveyance),0)

prob += lpSum(Amount_vars[i][j][k]*Cost[i][j][k] for (i,j,k) in routes)

for i in Source:
    prob += lpSum(Amount_vars[i][j][k] for j in Destination for k in Conveyance) <= Supply[i]

for j in Destination:
    prob += lpSum(Amount_vars[i][j][k] for i in Source for k in Conveyance) >= Demand[j]
    
for k in Conveyance:
    prob += lpSum(Amount_vars[i][j][k] for i in Source for j in Destination) <= capacity[k]

prob.solve()

print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
prob += lpSum(Amount_vars[i][j][k]*Cost[i][j][k] for (i,j,k) in routes)
```

throws `KeyError: 1` because you're accessing the elements of `Amount_vars` and `Cost` with the wrong indexing. What exactly are you trying to pass to `lpSum` in this line? It expects a vector...

Both `Amount_vars` and `Cost` are dictionaries of *different* length (4 and 35, respectively). You can access the different cost values stored in `Cost` by iterating over the values. Example to print each one:

```
for c in Cost.values():                                                                                 
    print(c)
```

If you want to multiply these 35 values to something, you should match the dimensions of `Cost` when using an iterable, like presumably you're trying in the line in question. As for `Amount_vars`, it is not clear what information you're trying to extract, but you should probably redefine `Source`, `Destination`, and `Conveyance` in order to match the length of `Cost`.

Comment: Thank you for response :). In the variable named "Amount_vars", I am tring to make a dictionary whose size is 35 (number of source * number of destination *number of conveyance -1= 4*3*3-1). But I am not getting the exact size which I desired.

Comment: Looks like `Cost` should be of size 36 then. Looking at that variable, there seems to be a duplicated key: `(3,7,8):2.049390153,(3,7,8):2.073644135`. Is the intent to assign `(3,7,9)` instead?

Comment: I think it would also be helpful to explain the rationale behind the line that actually produces the error. What is the intent of multiplying `Amount_vars[i][j][k]*Cost[i][j][k] `  ?  What exact numbers in `Amount_vars` are you trying to multiply here?

Comment: cost[i][j][k] is a three dimensional matrix representing per unit cost for the transported item from ith source to jth destination through kth conveyance while x[i][j][k] is unit item transported to i source to j destination through k conveyance. by multipling these two, i will get final transportation cost

Comment: Amount_vars = LpVariable.dicts("amountship", [(i,j,k) for i in Source j in Destination k in Conveyance],0). using LpVariabe.dicts, I am tring to define all 36 decision variable. But, I am getting syntex error.

Comment: Amount_vars ={}
for i in Source:
   for j in Destination:
       for k in Conveyance:
           Amount_vars[i][j][k] = None. I also try using for loop but not getting desired output.

Comment: I understand that you want the tuple i,j,k  to be the "label" of each element of Amount_vars. What do you want the value to be? `None` for all  i, j, k?

Comment: I don't have any idea how i should initialize Amount_vars. final value of Amount_vars , i will get by solving the problem.

Comment: OK so in that case it's enough to initialize it to zero. What is the exact structure of `Amount_vars` that you want? Is it the same as for `Cost` ? Do you want it to be a `dict` just like `Cost` ?

Comment: File "E:\Python_code\STP_1.py", line 32, in <module>
    Amount_vars[i][j][k] = 0
KeyError: 1. I am still getting the error. each value of Amount_vars map to their corresponding cost. for eg amount_vars[1][1][2] correspond to costs[1][1][2], and amount_vars[1][3][2] correspond to costs[1][3][2] etc.